# Write a java program to restart glassfish every day

Tags: java, glassfish

Glassfish would hang every one or two days, I had to manually restart the server. This is quite annoying and I think the problem is that the server run out of memory? 
So I am been thinking to write a java program to auto restart the server every day. 
Any one also experience the same problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why a Java program? Isn't there a start/stop command for Glassfish that you can trigger (from cron).

Comment: Nice idea, not really the place for it, SO's not a coding factory.  Have you considered trying something yourself?

Comment: Sounds like restarting the server is avoiding the issue. You should probably go debug the logs and try to figure out why the server keeps having problems in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that once the server started, a process called java.exe will run, and the ram will increase by time, when it reach to the limit of the java virtual memory. The server will stop. I have no idea why, I tried debug but I found nothing weird.

Comment: I recommend to *fix the application problem* (maybe a memory leak problem). Restarting GlassFish is just a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of glassfish. But in our case, we have a series of commands in order to stop and restart a server.

Do the following:

1. Create a bat file say `abc.bat` containing commands like below:

   ```
   kill - all - tasks
   stop - server
   SLEEP 10  --> Number of seconds taken by the server to stop. You can put more value for safety.
   start - myserver
   ```
2. Create a java say `ServerStopStart.java` using process.

   ```
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TRIGGER_MY_BATCH_FILE);
   ```
3. Using crontab or some other scheduling mechanism, schedule to run the ServerStopStart.java at mid-night or any other appropriate time when user load is NIL.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at the cause of the problem and work on it, rather than restarting.

One way to do this, on Windows atleast, would be create a batch file to stop and start the glassfish and execute this from your java application or just schedule it.

asadmin stop-domain

asadmin start-domain